# Best practice working with python variables in javascript django

Tags: javascript, python, django, vuejs2

I am currently accessing my python data in JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
    var x = {{ x | safe}};
    var l = {{ l | safe }};
    var sf ={{ sf | safe }};
</script>
```

this works but does not seem like the most ideal way to transfer data. What is the best practice for accessing and saving data between python and javascript using django?

What I am trying to do is send data from the view, manipulate it using the ui in javascript/vue.js and then save the calculated data.

Comment: If you're using Vue, it seems like it would make more sense to create an API endpoint that serves the data as JSON and accepts updates to it via POST or PATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you're asking about. I would recommend using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create a RESTful API as the "best practice" for interacting with a JS client-side app.

The most helpful way forward might be to [start with a tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-rest-vuejs/) and then return as more specific questions come up.